# ActionExecutionSpecification and BehaviorExecutionSpecification

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, specifications

With regard to UML specification superstructure i read about

### ActionExecutionSpecification and BehaviorExecutionSpecification

What is the differences between them?

In which cases i should use each one of them?

Comment: You might want not to expect too much precision from the UML spec. See http://www.omg.org/issues/issue15239.txt as an example for a typical discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Both `ActionExecutionSpecification` and `BehaviorExecutionSpecification` are specialization of `ExecutionSpecification`. They are used to map respectively to `Action` and `Behavior` concepts.

Refer to the respective superstructure chapters for more information on UML `Action` and `Behavior` semantics.

Comment: Why? The ExecutionSpecification elements are only used to map either an UML Action or an UML Behavior. There is nothing much to say about their differences and use cases. The OP did not ask about the difference between UML Action and Behavior concepts.

Comment: As the difference lies in Action and Behavior the original poster obviously asks for exactly that difference - which is not explained in your answer (so actually the answer means "rtfm" :)

Comment: Do you try explaining the difference between nails and hairs if someone asks you the difference between a "nail cutter" and a "hair cutter"?? Sorry for the poor analogy but it is exactly the same situation here... If the OP wants to know the difference between Behavior and Action in UML he should definitely rephrase its question this way.

Comment: thank you very much @Christian yes, i am looking for the exact differences between them and also in which cases i should use each one of them while modelling.

Comment: @greydet for sure Christian is an active member and didn't intent to bother you. You should read the question many times before post your answer because poster looking for a responsible answer.I hope i can find an answer for this questions